# Visual Studio and Salesforce CLI : Not able to authorize org

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, visualstudiocode

I just recently to download Salesforce CLI +  Visual Studio with Salesforce Extension Pack.

I tried to retrieve code from Salesforce instance not from Scratch org. Just for your knowledge, I am not trying to use Devhub/Stracth org but I only want to retrieve code like using Sublime. I refer to this [Org Development Model with VS Code](https://forcedotcom.github.io/salesforcedx-vscode/articles/user-guide/org-development-model) .

Because it fail for several attempts, I google and some of the solution that I found is to create Connected Apps and so I did. But still fail.

I also key in proxy

```
{
    "http.proxy": "http://1xxxxx:8080"
}
{
    "salesforcedx-vscode-apex.java.home":
    "c:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_201"
}
```

When I keyin the command Authorize an Org , it will open browser ,login page to Salesforce. After I key in my user name and password it gives this error.

Here the error message :
[image]

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully my answer can help other peoples, I was mistundersto od on Http proxy. Apparently we should setup it in Environment Variables like picture below:
[image]

Then make sure restart your Visual Studio. In my case I have to uninstall Salesforce Extension Pack and reinstall in after I setting up Http proxy in Environment Variable.